# File structure corruption after installing ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partition-recovery

I am using Windows 7. When I installed Ubuntu and ran it for the first time, everything was going fine. I booted Ubuntu and accessed my FAT32 and NTFS partitions.

After restarting Ubuntu, I booted to Windows 7. The operating system is working fine, but some of the installed applications like firefox, opera etc. are not working and my important data in other partitions is corrupted.

While accessing any folder in the corrupted partition, a message box appears with text:

> d:\backup is not accessible
>
> The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

While running Mozilla Firefox installed in windows 7, a message box appears with text:

> The program can't start because smime3.dll is missig from your computer.Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

Solutions?

Comment: Is your D still visible in explorer? Computer manager? Did you resize any partitions as part of the ubuntu install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can try ntfsprogs ([here you can see the complete set of commands](http://www.linux-ntfs.org/doku.php?id=ntfsprogs)) from Ubuntu (some kind of repair) or try using chkdsk from Win itself. OR if the files are in use, you can try the Win7 install DVD, recovery console. Thats all I can think of at the moment. Hope this helps... :/

Comment: Fortunately, Rollback RX Professional was installed on my PC and restore from previously taken snapshot and recovered my data.

Hadn't problem been solved, I would try time definitely !!

Anyways thanks for the response !!

Comment: Heh, no problem. :)